# Avoid specifying end time in Oozie Coordinator

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

In my oozie coordinator.xml i dont want to specify the end time.
Is there any way to do that.

**coordinator.xml**

```
 <coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="60" start="2009-02-01T00:00Z" end="2009-02-02T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
    <action>
       <workflow>
          <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/workflows</app-path>
       </workflow>
    </action>     
 </coordinator-app>
```

Answer (score 4):

No. Specify some time in the distant future, like "2109-02-02T00:00Z".